# Creating a Test and Prod CAB for my Windows Mobile 6 application

Tags: windows-mobile-6, deployment-project

My client wants me to have a test and prod version of my app that can be installed side by side on the same device. I don't want to duplicate and maintain separate code bases so I created separate deployment projects and added a config file in the test deployment project that had a test setting on. This idea seems really naive and brittle and it's mostly because I don't know better. If someone has a better idea about how to do this (and help me not to embarrass myself) or can point me to a good resource, I'd much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the idea of having test and prod deployment projects for in my windows mobile solution. Haven't had any issues but I still feel there's a better way